# Limit query result once value has been reached

Tags: sql, stock, portfolio

For my Stock portfolio I have two tables:

1. The Date, Open, Close, High, Low for all stocks in my portfolio.
2. The stocks I've picked, along with a target price for the stock to hit. Ticker, Target

So my query result looks something like this:

[image]

The O,C,H,L data comes from an API feed, I would like my query result to stop reporting on a ticker (in this case ALGN), once the value in the "high" column exceeds the value in the "target" column.

If not, the query result will continue to show me O,C,H,L data for a stock I have already sold and is no longer in my portfolio.

Would I use a CASE expression?

23/08/2021 22:46

I have added in a CASE expression that shows me the date my trade hit the desired target, however, my query result continues to show data after the target has been hit.

[image]

ideally after 2021-02-04, my query would stop giving me data for that ticker....

Comment: Wouldn't simple `WHERE high <= Target` be sufficient in this case!?

Comment: There is no row where high is greater than target in your example. But let's say We add a row with high = 630. And then maybe a row with high = 620. And then a row with high = 640. What is the query supposed to do then? Show all rows until high = 630 (i.e. don't show the rows that follow after the first row that exceeds high)? Or show all rows *before* high = 630? Or show no rows at all, because there exists a row that exceeds the limit? Or something else still?

Comment: let's say the next row shows 20/01/2021 and a high of 630. The target has been hit, so therefore, there is no need for my query results to continue showing O,C,L,H data for that particular stock after the 20/01/2021. It Stops there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(case when high > target then date end) over (partition by ticker) as first_target_date
      from t
     ) t
where date >= first_target_date or
      first_target_date is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method is to use a correlated subquery.

```
Select t.*
From mytable t
Where t.date <= (
    Select min(date) From mytable x
    Where x.ticker=t.ticker
      and x.high>x.Target
)
```